# How to get all volumes attached with vm in vphere in java api?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-tools

[image of vm description, I can see 2 hard disk is being used by VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7ym.png)

How can I get list of all volumes attached with VM in vSphere using java api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mean time, I found the answer. All courtesy to *Deadline*

```
    VirtualMachine vm = getVM(); // get the vm object

    List<VirtualDisk> virtualDiskList = new ArrayList<VirtualDisk>();
    VirtualMachineConfigInfo vmConfig = vm.getConfig();
    VirtualDevice[] vds = vmConfig.getHardware().getDevice();
    for(VirtualDevice vd : vds){
        if(vd instanceof VirtualDisk){
            virtualDiskList.add((VirtualDisk)vd);
        }
    }
```

Now virtualDiskList contains all virtual disks(volumes) attached with the given instance.